# How to get rid of unneeded vertices?

Tags: vertices

I have some objects that were made by joining two objects together. This results in a plane that cuts through the object (see below):

[image: unneeded plane]

I already removed the doubles, but is there some way I can remove the plane itself, so the four vertices there go away?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, delete the inner face by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> > <kbd>F</kbd>. Next select the edge loop and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to bring up the *Edges* menu, and then press <kbd>G</kbd> to select *Edge Slide*. Now slide the edge to the top or the bottom:

[image: Edge Slide]

Now select all with <kbd>A</kbd> and remove doubles with <kbd>W</kbd> to bring up the *Specials* menu and then <kbd>R</kbd> to select *Remove Doubles*. You should now be back to your standard cube mesh shape:

[image: Remove Doubles]

Comment: Sliding and removing doubles seems a bit cumbersome when X > Edge Loops does it in one.